# Input field type text has property onkeypress call function more then one time

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<input type=text id=Keywordtextbox onkeypress=fb()  maxlength="30" style=width:100px >
```

The function `fb()` is:

```
function fb() {    
        $("#Keywordtextbox").keypress(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                alert('123');
              //  document.getElementById('AddButton').click();
            }
        });           
}
```

My problem is when is the click enter event is not fired. When I click a second time it shows me an alert box; when I click on third time it shows me the alert three times. How can I handle that event so on <kbd>enter</kbd> key press only once time this `fb()` function is called.

Comment: <input type=text id=Keywordtextbox onkeypress=fb()  maxlength="30" style=width:100px> i call fb() function from input field like that

Comment: Take the alert out and put a console.log() in instead.  The alert may be getting in the way of seeing what is really happening.

Comment: my simple question is i only call fb() function once when i click enter that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call fb in onKeyPress AND register the .keypress jQuery event.  Do one or the other, not both!  You have double registered for key events and then after the first key, you get triple registered.

When you get a key event, it calls both fb() and it calls your inner function handler for .keyPress.  When fb() gets called again, you end up registering again for the keypress event and that happens each time a new key is pressed.

I'd recommend you get rid of the onkeypress=fb() from the HTML.

Then, just call fb() once in your startup code to register the keypress event handler.  After that, you should just get one key event per press.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Zyftj/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="Keywordtextbox"  maxlength="30" style="width:100px">
```

JS (called in page ready handler):

```
$("#Keywordtextbox").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log("123");
    }
});
```

Comment: ok i understand if i use only function fb(){ } so how i found that the press key is enter

Comment: I filled in a working example.  You can see it in action in the jsfiddle.